# Comparing completion rates of 4 assessments

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am trying to compare completion rates of 4 online assessments, A1, A2, B1, B2. A2 is the modified version of A1, B2 is the modified version of B1. I have categorical variable of Completed, Not Completed for each participant (total around 15,000 participants).Probably very igmorant questions.

1. Could I combine A1 and A2, B1 and B2 and do the T-test for comparing A and B? (Ideally we would like to compare A vs B). Or ANOVA is more recommended?
2. A1 has 4-5 more sample size compared to other assessments (this was assigned more frequently). Would this difference become a problem? If so could I randomly sample from A1 so that they are all about the same sample size?